# C# Как добавить статический список в класс

Tags: c#, visual-studio, list

Всем доброго дня! Помогите пожалуйста с решением задачки, делаю задания в C# и столкнулся с дополнительным заданием.
Суть задания такова, необходимо создать приложение WindowsForms, добавить 2 класса (1 из них должен наследовать).

Класс родитель product

```
    class product
{
    public string id;
    public string name;
    public int price;

    public product(string id, string name, int price)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public virtual string ShowInfo()
    {
        string info;
        info = "ID: " + this.id + "; Наименование: " + this.name + "; Цена: " + this.price;

        return info;
    }
    public static List<product> productList = new List<product>();
}}
```

Подкласс keyboard

```
    class keyboard : product
{
    public string keyboardtype;
    public string madein;
    public string keyboardcolor;
    public int keysnumber;

    public override string ShowInfo()
    {
        string info;

        info = "ID: " + this.id + "; Наименование: " + this.name + "; Цена: " + this.price + "\r\nТип клавиатуры: " + this.madein + "; Переключатели: "
            + this.madein + "; Цвет: " + this.keyboardcolor + "; Количество клавиш: " + this.keysnumber + Environment.NewLine;

        return info;
    }

    public keyboard(string id, string name, int price, string keyboardtype, string madein, string keyboardcolor, int keysnumber) : base(id, name, price)
    {
        this.keyboardtype = keyboardtype;
        this.madein = madein;
        this.keyboardcolor = keyboardcolor;
        this.keysnumber = keysnumber;
    }

    public keyboard(string id, string name, int price, string keyboardtype, string madein, string keyboardcolor) : base(id, name, price)
    {
        this.keyboardtype = keyboardtype;
        this.madein = madein;
        this.keyboardcolor = keyboardcolor;
    }

    public keyboard(string id, string name, int price, string keyboardtype, string madein) : base(id, name, price)
    {
        this.keyboardtype = keyboardtype;
        this.madein = madein;
    }

    public keyboard(string id, string name, int price, string keyboardtype) : base(id, name, price)
    {
        this.keyboardtype = keyboardtype;
    }
}}
```

Код формы (весь код отрабатывается после нажатия на кнопку)

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        product new_product;
        product new_keyboard;

        if (IdBox.Text != "" && NameBox.Text != "" && PriceBox.Text != "")
        {
            if (KeyboardType.Text != "")
            {
                if (MadeIn.Text != "")
                {
                    if (KeyboardColor.Text != "")
                    {
                        if (KeysNumber.Text != "")
                        {
                            new_keyboard = new keyboard(IdBox.Text, NameBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(PriceBox.Text), KeyboardType.Text, MadeIn.Text, KeyboardColor.Text, Convert.ToInt32(KeysNumber.Text));
                            ResultBox.Text += new_keyboard.ShowInfo();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            new_keyboard = new keyboard(IdBox.Text, NameBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(PriceBox.Text), KeyboardType.Text, MadeIn.Text, KeyboardColor.Text);
                            ResultBox.Text += new_keyboard.ShowInfo();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        new_keyboard = new keyboard(IdBox.Text, NameBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(PriceBox.Text), KeyboardType.Text, MadeIn.Text);
                        ResultBox.Text += new_keyboard.ShowInfo();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    new_keyboard = new keyboard(IdBox.Text, NameBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(PriceBox.Text), KeyboardType.Text);
                    ResultBox.Text += new_keyboard.ShowInfo();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                new_product = new product(IdBox.Text, NameBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(PriceBox.Text));

                ResultBox.Text += new_product.ShowInfo();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Заполните обязательные поля!");
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        product new_product;
        if (IdBox.Text != "" && NameBox.Text != "" && PriceBox.Text != "")
        {
            List.productList.Add(IdBox.Text, NameBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(PriceBox.Text));
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Заполните поля!");
        }
    }
}}
```

Сама форма выглядит так
[image: Форма приложения]

В общем вопрос такой, в задании необходимо:

1. Добавить в базовый класс статический лист Корзина с типом Product и метод добавления текущего товара в корзину.
2. Реализовать метод, возвращающий суммарную цену товаров в корзине.

Я пытался везде искать как добавить список в класс product, а затем добавить в него какие-нибудь элементы введённые в TextBox при нажатии на кнопку в Form1.cs.
Сейчас уже код не сохранил, но последнее что я сделал это создал список public static void List, ошибок в коде не было, но при попытке добавить значения из TextBox в список, например "List.Add(TextBox.Text)", выдавало ошибку что List не существует в данном контексте или что-то такое.

Comment: Не совсем понятно про первый пункт, что он значит?

Comment: Назваия классов в C# с большой буквы принято писать.

Answer (score 1):

```
class product
{
    public string id;
    public string name;
    public int price;

    public product(string id, string name, int price)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;

        productList.Add(this); // <---
    }

    ...
```